# Angular model driven validator conditional to a control value

Tags: angular

I'm currently defining a model driven form with `formBuilder`. In this form there is a radio button. And if the value of this radio button is `true` then I want to display additional inputs which only then are required.

If the radio is `false` then the additional inputs can be empty and must not block form submit.

Here is the formbuilder part, how can I make my scenario work?

```js
initDynamicForm() {
    let name = '';
    let moreData = false;
    let email = '';

    this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [ name, Validators.required ],
      moreData: moreData,
      email: email // HERE: if moreData is true => must be required
    });
  }
```

Any idea on how to set this dynamically defined Validators.required on `email` input depending on `moreData` value?

*Fact to mention: `dynamicForm` is called several times inside a `*ngFor` loop. Thus I can't defined component level attributes to be used because each form using dynamicForm "template" must work independently.*

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable, perhaps the easiest way is to disable `email` field when the radio button is `false`, because this means the email-field will not be included in the form, thus it doesn't affect the validity of the form.

So I'd put a function, that checks the value of the radio button:

```ts
this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required ],
  moreData: [false, this.checkMoreData.bind(this)]
  email: ['', Validators.required] 
});
```

And then the function:

```ts
checkMoreData(control: FormControl) {
  if(control.value == true) {
    this.myForm.get('email').enable()
  }
  // we have to check if myForm is not undefined (since it will be upon initialization)
  // also check if the control is not undefined
  else if (this.myForm && control) {
    this.myForm.get('email').disable()
  }
}
```

In the end, if you do need to get all fields, disabled or not, you can use `getRawValue`, which also includes any disabled fields.

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YjPQBKUogI8LGE2tKWB4?p=preview)

Comment: Intersting solution. Will give it a shot. Maybe I could also move email to a separate group and then maybe "injecting" it dynamically. Will try to think about it!

Comment: Sure, try it out, perhaps you find a more suitable solution for you, but thought I'd throw it out there. Maybe you come up with a nice spin-off or better solution. Let me know if you do, this was an interesting question :) Happy coding!